# cpp pass by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

i wrote a simple sorting code on pass by reference. here i am passing an array to function and then performing the sorting operation. after passing the array i am printing the entire array as entered by user then performing the sorting operation(in descending order) but after sorting when i print the sorted array i get an output that the array index '0' contains the value '41'. if i enter the numbers less than '41' then the sorted array is displayed as '41',and then the other numbers in sorted manner. Please explain why i am getting such an output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int sort_array(int *p);

int main() {
    int arr[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << "enter " << (i+1) << " value:";
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }

    sort_array(arr);
    return 0;
}

int sort_array(int *p) {
    int c=0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << p[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "arr:"<<p[0];
    cout<<"\n";

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            if (p[j] < p[j+1]) {
            c=p[j];
            p[j]=p[j+1];
            p[j+1]=c;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << p[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << p[0];
}
```

Comment: Please include the initial values in your code instead of reading them from the commandline, both for convenience of the people that might want to help you and to make sure that that part doesn't cause the problem. Also, format that code consistently and include the expected and actual output in your question. You might also want to adjust the topic or the code, because there is not much relation to "pass by reference".

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to do a bubble sort on your array in `sort_array()`, but the logic is wrong.  Try using this code instead:

```
int sort_array(int *p) {
    int c=0;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << p[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "arr:" << p[0];
    cout << "\n";

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j < (10-i); j++) {
            if (p[j-1] > p[j]) {
                c = p[j-1];
                p[j-1] = p[j];
                p[j] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << p[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout<<p[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your sorting. j is from 0 to 9, and than you access `p[j+1]` when `j = 9`, `p[10]` is outside your array boundaries.

So fix your following part to proper sorting.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(p[j]<p[j+1])
        {
            c=p[j];
            p[j]=p[j+1];
            p[j+1]=c;
       }
    }
}
```

Clarification: the code above is the problematic part of the original code posted. This is NOT the fixed sorting. That is the part to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        if(p[j]<p[j+1])
        {
            c=p[j];
            p[j]=p[j+1];
            p[j+1]=c;
        }
    }
}
```

the sorting works fine once i changed the limit of inner loop. the problem was accessing the array index [10] but i had it declared till index [9].